# CFX using encrypted password in properties file

Tags: cxf, ws-security, password-encryption

I am using CXF for my webservice security. I have the following configuration:

```
  <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="PasswordCallbackHandler"/>
  <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="WEB-INF/keystore.properties"/>
  <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="WEB-INF/keystore.properties"/>
  <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="useReqSigCert"/>
```

Currently we store the password in keystore.properties as plaintext password. I want to store an encrypted password and then have that used to log into the keystore.

Any idea what i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF 3.0.0 supports using encrypted passwords in Crypto properties files. The CallbackHandler must supply the password used to decrypt the encrypted password in this scenario. See here for more information:

http://ws.apache.org/wss4j/newfeatures20.html

http://coheigea.blogspot.ie/2014/02/apache-wss4j-200-part-iv.html

Colm.